# how to manage the use of both $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in action of form and htaccess for urlrewriting together for same page?

Tags: php, form-submit, url-rewriting

how to manage the use of both $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in action of form and htaccess for url-rewriting?

If I submit a form and in the action attribute of it i pass "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" and at the same time i am using url rewriting for the same page.. then these two things will contradict each other resulting in the display of action value of form in address bar.. so how can i manage this to get the url rewrited form of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

here the rewrite rule is to change the name of url file likewise as if form is submitted to any file say **direction.php** then rewrite will change it to something **30/redirect.html**

Comment: Please explain this better. What is the rewrite rule supposed to do and why does it interfere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what rewrite setup  you have got so my guess is you have to specify the url in form action. You'd not be able to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] as it will return the path of file which is actually being executed.

For example:

```
<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
to
<form action="'./url/as/per/rewrite'].'">
```

If this doesn't serve the purpose. You can have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
```

and update the form action value.

I hope it helps.